# Regex for Google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to match a set of data but not if it contains certain strings in the query:

The strings that I do not want to allow are

```
/hd/805
/hd/864
/hd/999
/hd/???????debugUser??????
/hd/208?debugUser=test&MediaCode=XXXXX&CMP=XXXXX
/hd/208?debugUser=john&MediaCode=XXXXX&CMP=XXXXX
```

But I do want to match everything else

```
/hd/123
/hd/654?test=test
```

etc

I have this regex to exclude the first part `/hd/(?!864)(?!805)(?!999)[0-9]+`

But I cannot get it to catch if the string contains debugUser

I have tried `/hd/(?!864)(?!805)(?!999)[0-9]+\??(?!\?debugUser.*).*`

But that still includes the url

Does anyone have ideas?

This regular expression will be used with google analytics.

Comment: Im not familiar with google analytics, but is the 805, 864, 999, 123 and other number constant? IE Will you ever get a 421?

Comment: I want the url to match if it contains anything but those I have pages line /hd/123.* that I want to be included but if it starts out with /hd/999 etc not to be. The first string I have excludes thoese from matching but I cant get it to exclude the string if it contains the debugUser in the url

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use this regex: `/hd/(805|864|999|208|\?\?\?\?\?\?\?debugUser\?\?\?\?\?\?)` to match to the ones you *don't* want, and if it matches then just ignore it. So your psuedo code will look like -

```
for(String url : urls){
    if(regex.matches(url) continue;
    //else do processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern to check a string or a line in multiline mode that contains only an uri:

```
^\/hd\/(?:[0-7]|8(?!05\b|64\b)|9(?!99\b))\d*(?:\?(?:[^d\s]+|d+(?!ebugUser))+)?$
```

or this to find the string you want inside a larger string:

```
(?<=^|["']|\s)\/hd\/(?:[0-7]|8(?!05\b|64\b)|9(?!99\b))\d*(?:\?(?:[^d\s]+|d+(?!ebugUser))+)?(?=\s|['"]|$)
```

*for this one, don't forget to escape the quote (single or double) you use.*